# use regex to replace all but first occurrence of a substring of blanks

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

The following statement runs fine:

```
$wb.upLinearLoad.append('<div>' + sprintf("%5s%8.1f to%7.1f%8.1f%6.0f%8.0f",sLinearSegName[i][j],fLinearPtBA[i][j],fLinearPtBA[i][j+1],fLen,fLinearPtPpi[i][j],fLinearSegMaxWt[i][j]).replace(/ /," &nbsp;") + '</div>');
```

However, I now have a need to dynamically change the color of the last two variables only, so I decided to enclose them in a span with a class='wt' to control their color. This gives:

```
$wb.upLinearLoad.append('<div>' + sprintf("%5s%8.1f to%7.1f%8.1f<span class='wt'>%6.0f%8.0f</span>",sLinearSegName[i][j],fLinearPtBA[i][j],fLinearPtBA[i][j+1],fLen,fLinearPtPpi[i][j],fLinearSegMaxWt[i][j]).replace(/ /," &nbsp;") + '</div>');
```

which fails because the space between span and class gets changed to `&nbsp;`

My regex ability goes only as far the example, so the question becomes how do I change all but the first space to `&nbsp;`?

Any and all suggestions are most welcome, and especially if you see that my whole approach is poor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't do it using strings. Instead, use the jQuery/DOM manipulation. It's less prone to error and more efficient.

```
$wb.upLinearLoad.append(
    $('<div>').append(
        sprintf("%5s%8.1f to%7.1f%8.1f", sLinearSegName[i][j], fLinearPtBA[i][j], fLinearPtBA[i][j+1], fLen),
        $('<span>').addClass('wt').text(sprintf("%6.0f%8.0f</span>", fLinearPtPpi[i][j], fLinearSegMaxWt[i][j]))[0]
    )
);
```

Comment: While a copy and paste of minitech's suggestion produced a jumbled display, I think he has pointed me in the right direction although I have yet to fully understand it. For the moment, I have it working by doing the following:    $wb.upLinearLoad.append('<div>' + sprintf("%5s%8.1f to%7.1f%8.1f",sLinearSegName[i][j],fLinearPtBA[i][j],fLinearPtBA[i][j+1],fLen).replace(/ /g,"&nbsp;") + '<span class="wt">' + sprintf('%6.0f%8.0f',fLinearPtPpi[i][j],fLinearSegMaxWt[i][j]).replace(/ /g,"&nbsp;") + '</span></div>');
but I think what I need to do is understand how to use append and text simultaneously.

Comment: @Terry: There was a little problem in my code, sorry. Try it again, it should work now.